# PHP REGEX to convert links to hyperlink in string - remove last period

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

I have the following code to convert links to hyperlinks in a string.

```
$text_block = preg_replace('$(\s|^)(https?://[a-z0-9_./?=&-]+)(?![^<>]*>)$i', ' <a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a> ',$text_block);
```

However, if the link as a period at the end, like "do a search on http://google.com.", the regex includes the period in the link. How can I change the regex above to look for and not include a period if present?

EDIT: For clarification - the `$text_block` is a large block of text that may contain many links. The regex need to parse through the block of text and find and convert all found links.

EDIT 2: As pointed out below in the comments, I guess you'd have to account for domains like ".co.uk". So I guess it would have to look for and remove the last period that is followed by whitespace, if present... gets tricky. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you determine when the period is and isn't needed?

Comment: @MikeBrant: probably when it is alone at the end.

Comment: Ah good point - hadn't considered .co.uk for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not particularly elegant, but purely regex solution is :

```
$(\s|^)(https?://[a-z0-9_./?=&-]+[a-z0-9_/?=&-])(?![^<>]*>)$i
```

Just ensures the last character is any of the valid characters except `.`

***PHP***

```
$text_block = preg_replace('$(\s|^)(https?://[a-z0-9_./?=&-]+[a-z0-9_/?=&-])(?![^<>]*>)$i', ' <a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a> ',$text_block);
```

[Working on RegExr](http://regexr.com?37a96)

Comment: OGHaza - that works perfectly. Thank you so much. Would I be able to trouble you for the same exact regex criteria, but to find and replace email links? Or should I start a new question. I probably should have included it here in my original question

Comment: @Chris Just modified your regex again: `$(\s|^)([a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9_.-]+[a-z0-9_-])(?![^<>]*>)$i` [RegExr](http://regexr.com?37a99) You will almost certainly need to modify the allowed characters in each part, I just left them as `[a-z0-9_.-]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$output = rtrim($string, '.');
```

Comment: `TrimEnd()` doesn't exist in PHP.